# List from specific elements of output

Tags: python

I am building a script to get data from server logs.  The data arrive in the following format showing time stamps and frequency of occurrences.

```
20:52:37 - 3

20:52:38 - 8

20:52:39 - 28

20:52:40 - 58

20:52:41 - 59

20:52:42 - 51

20:52:43 - 37

20:52:44 - 22

20:52:45 - 4

20:52:47 - 14

20:52:48 - 15

20:52:49 - 12

20:52:50 - 4

20:52:51 - 5

20:52:52 - 12

20:52:53 - 5
```

I'm trying to create a list of just the numbers after the dash to appear like:

```
[3,8,28,etc.,etc.]
```

I've tried splitting the output and then adding just the desired element but keep hitting errors. trying to split on the dash and new line code then simply add the right position for each number:

```
 c = resp.split(' - ','\r\n\n')
    lst = c[::2]
    list = []
    list.append(lst)
    print(list)
```

Comment: Split only takes one argument to split on. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: `resp.strip('\n').split(' - ')[-1]`, but use a variable name that doesn't overwrite the built-in `list`, then `l = []`, `l.append(resp.strip('\n').split(' - ')[-1])`

Comment: are there really empty lines/linebreaks between the data lines?

Comment: Are you sure python is the right choice for this? Sounds like this type of problem would be very simple to solve with awk. Not that it can't be solved in python, or even C for that matter... But typically when I'm working with log parsing like this, and it's not involving complex computation or manipulation which would require python libraries, I use awk or even just bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = """
 20:52:37 - 3

 20:52:38 - 8

 20:52:39 - 28

 20:52:40 - 58

 20:52:41 - 59
 ....
 """

data = map(int, re.findall('(?<=\s-\s)\d+', s))
```

Output:

```
[3, 8, 28, 58, 59...]
```

Comment: thanks this was perfect.  I shouldve tried regular expressions :(

Comment: @JSimonsen glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

To remove trailing newlines you can use [rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
res = []

with open('server.log') as f:
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)  # to remove trailing newlines
    lines = (line for line in lines if line)  # to remove blank lines
    res = [int(line.split(' - ')[-1]) for line in lines]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[3, 8, 28, 58, 59, 51, 37, 22, 4, 14, 15, 12, 4, 5, 12, 5]
```